# Can I exclude /run from my backup scheme?

Tags: backup, rsync, directory-structure

I have written a rsync-based system backup for my Linux system. The aim is to be able to redeploy the system entirely from the saves, so I don't only backup homedirs. I have excluded a few top-level directories from the backup: `/proc`, `/sys`, `/mnt`, `/tmp`.

I wonder whether I can exclude `/run` and still be able to get a viable save? I observe that it takes a lot of disk space on my backup disk (mostly with `/run/shm`).

Answer (score 9):

`/run` is transient data, it's often on `tmpfs` to guarantee it's discarded when you shutdown. No point backing it up.

I would use the `-x`, `--one-file-system` option of `rsync` and backup only the filesystems you want to backup. That would automatically exclude the `/proc`, `/sys`, etc. and `/run` if it's on `tmpfs`, and would safeguard against users mounting fuse or remote file systems.

Something like:

```
rsync -x --relative --other-options / /boot destination/
```

Or even better, use LVM or any snapshotting file system like `btrfs`, `zfs`, `nilfs`... and take a snapshot before running `rsync` on the snapshot mounted read-only. That means you've got a better chance to have consistent data on the backup (and avoid `rsync` triggering automounts or updating access times for instance).

Comment: I'm not sure about the `-x` rsync option in my case. It would exclude `/run`, but apparently not `/proc` and `/sys`. Also, it would exclude (in my case, again) `/boot`, which I need. However, I will definitely look further into LVM snapshots. I already use LVM (which is not a FS...) on this machine but have never used this feature. Thanks.